# Android, store a couple of wav files

Tags: database, android, sqlite, audio

I'm generating about 6 wav audio files at runtime. I want to store them in internal memory. Is a blob to sqlite the right/recommended way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the recommended way but here is what I want to say, eitherways:

The advantages of storing these files in data base would be:
1.The related database is deleted once the application is uninstalled.
2.Files private to application

Disadvantage:
It will increase your application size.

Have you considered storing your files on SDcard? Also, have you taken a look at [CacheManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CacheManager.html)?

Comment: I'm considering using SharedPreferences and coding myself all of the logic. The files will be saved to data/data/my_package_name/some_special_folder.   Since I'm generating audio files, not downloading them, CacheManager doesn't seem to fit in here. But thanks for pointing to CacheManager anyway, I'll use it later.

Saving to /sdcard is not an option in my case. The generated audio files must be deleted once the app is uninstalled and saving them to the internal memory seems a way of achieving that. 

I'm quite new to Android and many of my assumptions could be wrong of course.